# Transfer Python code to another machine - stops working

Tags: python

I have a program in Python that works perfectly well. When I transfer my program over to another machine and try to run it on there, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program1.py", line 3, in <module>
    import scipy.spatial as sp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ckdtree import *
  File "numpy.pxd", line 30, in scipy.spatial.ckdtree (scipy/spatial/ckdtree.c:6087)
ValueError: numpy.dtype does not appear to be the correct type object
```

Is this just a result of the new machine not having the correct modules installed or something like this?

Thank you!

---

Computer which runs the code:
Python - 2.7.3
Numpy - 1.7.1
Scipy - 0.12.0

Computer which produces the error message above:
Python - 2.6.5
Numpy - 1.5.1
Scipy - 0.7.0

Of course ideally they would be the same, but I can't really change the versions on the second machine. Is it possible to identify which version is causing the problem?

Comment: Does the new machine have the same modules? Same versions? This isn't something people here can tell you! Does it even have the same version of Python?

Comment: Well I'm not sure. I can go ahead and find out all those things (I'm not able to right now), but I thought that someone who understood the error message would be able to tell me if it was a problem of that nature to begin with (or if I just had the wrong paths in my code now that I've moved it or something of that nature).

Comment: Sure you can, if you can open up the Python interpreter it will tell you what version of Python you're using. Then if you import numpy typing `numpy.version` in the interpreter will tell you what version of numpy you're using. Do it on both machines and as your problem seems to be in scipy would be worth checking that as well.

Comment: Well I know that my Python version is 2.7.3 and I have just asked, and apparently the version of the other machine is 2.6.5. How do I know if this is the problem?

Comment: You just found a major version difference. You will know if it's the problem by eliminating that difference and trying again. Do the same with the library version too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know where the error comes from, use the first machine to downgrade, numpy, scipy and python. try different combinations in order to reproduce the same bug.

I would suggest to have the same versions on your dev machine as on the machine you need it deployed. That way you won't have similar problems.

You might want to use pip and virtualenv so the config for this project won't affect the rest of your setup

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue like that some time ago. Was messing around with virtualenv and got an error similar to yours. Most likely because of the version. Some modules might be clashing.